# Future anidado en Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, login

Hola estoy realizando el login con Firebase pero de ahi tengo que consultar un api-rest con el uid de firebase, si esa consulta trae datos significa que el usuario esta registrado caso contrario le mostraria otra pantalla, me funciona si desde el api-rest trae datos, pero si no trae me manda este error

```
Exception has occurred.RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)
```

Aqui está el codigo donde consulto el estado de authStateChange, si ejecuto el codigo del api rest en un Future Builder me ejecuta sin problemas.

```
Future<void> _authStateChanged(AuthUser? user) async {
try {
  if (user == null) {
    return emit(AuthSignedOut());
  } else {
    final dataSource = RestDataSourceMySql();
    final usuario = await dataSource.getName(user.uid);
    print("Trajo datos de MySQl");
    print(usuario.cedula);
    if (usuario == null) {
      emit(AuthNoRegister(user));
    } else {
      emit(AuthSignedWithMysql(user));
    }
  }
} on Exception catch (e) {
  print("No trajo datos");
  //emit(AuthNoRegister(user));

}
```

}

Comment: Puedes agregar un ejemplo de cual es la respuesta cuando "el api-rest trae datos" y de cuando no trae datos ? Me refiero a los outputs que te devuelve la consulta.

Comment: {id: 1, uid: uWb0PKBbhBZVirLh0bllk2ncDRp1, nombres: Gregorio Cruz, correo: xxxx@hotmail.com, cedula: 181111111111} esto me trae cuando hay datos, pero cuando no trae nada sale el error que menciono

Comment: ¿Cuándo no hay datos la respuesta es null?

Comment: agrega más detalle, quizás el error está dentro del método dataSource.getName, lograste hacer debug ?

Comment: Consejo: pon el código relativo al fallo. En este caso, el bloc y el método, que lo tienes puesto. Los métodos más importantes que está llamando el bloc para hacer su trabajo: dataSource.getName. Y en este caso, creo que también sería importante ver la parte del código que reacciona al estado que no trae datos.